# Split string by different marks

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

how to split string by several different symbols, for example like dot `.` and `-` in `c#` string

```
string str = "sally-vikram.dean.sarah-ray";
```

but without  replace all to same mark:

```
str = str.Replace("-", "."):
```

and split by dot for example:

```
string[] words = str.Split('.');
```

to get:

```
sally
vikram
dean
sarah
ray
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`string.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) can actually take an array of values:

```
string[] words = str.Split('.', '-');
```

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, a regex [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions)) is a good choise:

```
string[] words = Regex.Split(str, "[.-]");
```

Note: Since `-` is also used to define a character range like `a-z` it's good practice to put the `-` at the end of character group. Otherwise, just escape it, e.g. `\-`.

This is most appropriate if you expected that you need further delimiters and other requirements, find the regex more readable, and performance isn't an issue (the Regex.Split is much slower than the String.Split equivalent).

Comment: No problem, though I think Regex is a little overkill for this situation, it would certainly work.

Comment: I think a regex solution is fine, it's very readable and can be extended easily. And performance shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Well some benchmarking tells me that Regex is 10 times slower than a pure `string.Split()` operation, that's why I'm saying it's overkill.

Comment: Regex is great for many situations. But when face with something that is an order of magnitude slower (and even before testing I would have guessed that), then why even waste time with the slower option?

Comment: I feel this is not a real argument here. The practical speed difference is most likely irrelevant.